# Script to check the alteration of crontab

Tags: linux, cron

Hi I Need a script to monitor the cron entries and if there is any change in the crontab entry it needs to alert me.
For this I have used the method by taking a copy of current crontab then it needs to compare the crontabs every day.If there is any alteration found it needs to alert me.Is this possible?

Currently I'm using `crontab -l > $(date +%Y%m%d).crontab` command to take copy every day and I think `diff` command can do the comparison
can any one please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like below script

```
CRDI=/var/spool/cron/crontabs
CHECKF=/tmp/last.crontab.check
ALERT=iam@userhost
if [ -f $CHECKF ]
then
find $CRDI -type f -newer $CHECKF | while read tabfile
do
   echo "Crontab file for user $(basename $tabfile) has changed" | mail -s "Crontab changed" $ALERT
done
fi
touch $CHECKF
```

Comment: Hi I need to check it in a regular manner...will it be possible?

Comment: Yeah, you can run it is root cron job

Comment: Thanks .but could you please tell why we are using this commands or the outcomes of this commands(for learning purpose)   1) -f $CHECKF and 2)find $CRDI -type f -newer $CHECKF | while read tabfile 3)touch $CHECKF

Comment: We are checking the current modified time of crontab file with last.crontab.check file. If crontab file is newer, we are mentioning to mail. Also after every check, date of last.crontab.check will be modified.

Comment: Thanks ganesh but I need to know about the above 3 commands...could you please explain about the above 3 commands..?

Comment: 1) check if file exists 2) We are checking the current modified time of crontab file with last.crontab.check file. 3) after every check, date of last.crontab.check will be modified

Comment: Thanks but if I'm using this script it will give alert if I make any changes even if the Change is correct.Actually it needs to look in a way that take copy of the current crontab in a file then every day a cron tab copy needs to be taken and it needs to compare using "diff" command if it is not matching it needs to send alert mail.Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer Thanks for your efforts

Hi, I finally got the answer Thanks for your efforts

```
#!/bin/sh
export smtp=smtprelay.intra.xxxx.com:25
ALERT=redmine@xxxx.com
crontab -l > /home/ssx00001/y.txt
cat y.txt
diff /home/ssx00001/x.txt  /home/ssx00001/y.txt > /home/ssx00001/z.txt
ab=`cat z.txt | wc -l`
echo $ab
if [[ $ab != 0 ]]; then
echo "Crontab for xxxx has changed" | mail  -s "Crontab modified" $ALERT
fi
```